# How to resolve that ? Identity Server 4, 500 Internal Server Error on .Net Core App

Tags: .net, azure, api, .net-core, identity

I have a dotnet core app on Azure Kubernetes Cluster. Identity Server 4 and api are runnig on the cluster. When i send a request my api then i get 500 error from api response. But if i try on my computer then i get success

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://xxx/identity-api/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://xxx/identity-api/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No route to host (xxx:443)

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (113): No route to host

How to resolve that ?

Comment: Any advice that ?

Comment: add below code in Startup-->Configure

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
| SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
| SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

Comment: Need to change from HTTPS to HTTP

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT thank you for your response i will try but i want to use https. Why i need to change that ?

Comment: it doesn't work @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT

Comment: Run the app at a command prompt on the server or enable the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: thanks for response. I already see the problem. You can see on above side. @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT
(System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://xxx/identity-api/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://xxx/identity-api/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No route to host (xxx:443)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (113): No route to host)

Comment: it was resolved,its a dns problem. Thank you.